# How to get Retrofit 2 error from array body

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

My current response is

```
{"response":"validation error","status":"failure","code":400,"errors":["You can not add multiple items with different categories"]}
```

My current code is :

```
String errorBody = response.errorBody().string();

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(errorBody.trim());
jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("errors");
Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
String errors = "";
while (keys.hasNext()) {
     String key = keys.next();
     JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray(key);
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
       errors += key + " : " + arr.getString(i) + "\n";
     }
}
```

I am trying to get the error code to see if it matches specific keywords to handle the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with this code:

```
String errors = "";
String errorBody = response.errorBody().string();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject rootObj = parser.parse(errorBody.trim()).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray errorArray = rootObj.getAsJsonArray("errors");
for (JsonElement pa : errorArray) {
    errors = pa.getAsString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your current code its not to good,better way for u is:

create modelClass for your json output and in retrofit calls write:

if (model.status=='failure' || model.code==400){

print(response.message) // or something like this

}

Comment: im getting different error msgs with the same error code so i need to check the error msg first

Answer (score 0):

You can look through the following code snippet

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<PagedResponse<NotificationModel>>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PagedResponse<NotificationModel>> call, Response<PagedResponse<NotificationModel>> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    try {
                        PagedResponse<NotificationModel> notifications = (PagedResponse<NotificationModel>) response.body();

                        tvRecordsCount.setText("Total "+response.body().getTotal()+" Notifications ");
                        showNotification(notifications);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    showToast(getApplicationContext(), "Server Error");
                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PagedResponse<NotificationModel>> call, Throwable t) {

            showToast(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```